# Create Azure website (app service) within a resource group with service plan with Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I looked on the web and I found only trival examples of usage New-AzureWebsite like:

```
    New-AzureWebsite -Name appName -Location yourLocation
```

However this commands creates a website in a new resource group and with new service plan. How to create a website within a existing resource group with existing service plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the new AzureRM Powershell v.1.0.1 and use the following command

```
New-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName <RGName> -AppServicePlan <AppServPlan> -Name <SiteName>
```

Comment: new to powershell azure, for New-AzureWebsite and New-AzureRMWebApp, which one is recommended?

Comment: New-AzureRmWebApp is the recommended cmdlet, as it uses Azure resource manager.

Comment: Parameter AppServicePlanName is now called AppServicePlan only

Comment: Thanks @Sven, I have updated my comment, for more information you can check the article that explains the different commands:
http://aka.ms/webapp-powershell

Comment: @AhmedElnably how does one deploy actual web app into created AzureRmWebApp instance? Neither this answer nor linked article have any suggestions..